# how to prove : $(p-1)!\equiv p-1 \pmod {p(p-1)})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to prove : $$(p-1)!\equiv p-1 \pmod {p(p-1)})$$

my efford :

we have: $(p-1)!\equiv-1\equiv p-1\pmod p$ but $(p-1)!\equiv 0\pmod {p-1}$

if $(p-1)!\equiv p-1\pmod {p-1}$ then we had $(p,p-1)=1$ then $(p-1)!\equiv p-1 \pmod {p(p-1)} )$

Comment: But $p-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$ (look up the definition of $\equiv$ if you're in doubt).

Comment: Good, you are finished.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By Wilson's theorem, $(p -1)! \equiv p - 1 \pmod{p}$, and it obviously is $(p -1)! \equiv 0 \pmod{p -1}$. As $\gcd(p - 1, p) = 1$, can combine by the chinese remainder theorem...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ (p\!-\!1)!-(p\!-\!1)\, =\, (p\!-\!1)n,\,\ n = \color{#C00}{(p\!-\!2)!-1},\:$ and $\rm\:p\mid n\:$ by Wilson's Theorem.

**Note** $\rm\,\ mod\ p\!:\,\ \color{#C00}{(p\!-\!2)! \equiv 1} \!\iff\! (p\!-\!1)!\equiv -1,\ $ by multiplying or dividing by $\rm\:p\!-\!1 \equiv -1.\ $ Therefore one may call either of these equivalent statements "Wilson's Theorem".